# Dynamic DB selection (EJB 3.0 with Glassfish managed JTA server)

Tags: glassfish, ejb, database-connection, jta

We are using JTA through Glassfish server managed dataSource, But we have a separate DB for Each client, How can I select DB dynamically according to user Logged In.
  If i set transaction type "local" in "persistance.xml" and define properties before creating entity manager through properties map then it works correctly but if I define properties with transaction type "JTA" then properties set through properties map are ignored.

```
    Map props = new HashMap();  

    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.18:3306/af_db"); 
    EntityManagerFactory  emf = ersistence.createEntityManagerFactory
      ("XXXJPA", props);
    em =emf.createEntityManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JTA you cannot use EntityManagerFactory. So, you have to create separate EntityManager for each user and select it dinamicaly.